# Can I add a link to the node reference when using the autocomplete widget?

Tags: 7, nodes, ajax

I love the autocomplete widget for the References module in Drupal 7, but I find it odd that it doesn't include either a link to the referenced node (view or edit)?

Is there some way in hook_form_alter that I can add this somehow?

---

I can do this:

```
$form['field_lessons']['und'][0]['#suffix'] = '<a href="#">Edit</a>';
```

And the autocomplete field has an edit link underneath of it, but this doesn't work:

```
foreach($form['field_lessons']['und'] AS $lesson) {
  $lesson['#suffix'] = '<a href="#">Edit</a>';
}
```

And also loops 10+ times even though I only have 1 node reference currently :s

---

I don't necessarily like it but I can do it in Javascript like this and the Drag & Drop still works:

```
$('#edit-field-lessons .form-item').each(function(i) {
  var lesson_nid = $(this).find('input[type="text"]').val();
  lesson_nid = lesson_nid.substring(lesson_nid.indexOf('[nid:')+5, lesson_nid.indexOf(']'));

  $(this).append('<a class="view" href="node/' + lesson_nid + '">View</a>');
  $(this).append('<a class="edit" href="node/' + lesson_nid + '/edit">Edit</a>');
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This'll do the trick (I've tested it this time ;) ):

```
foreach($form['field_lessons'][LANGUAGE_NONE] as $key => $lesson) {
  // If we have a default value for the nid, we have a populated node reference
  if (isset($lesson['nid']) && is_array($lesson['nid']) && $lesson['nid']['#default_value'])) {
    // Get the nid
    $nid = $lesson['nid']['#default_value'];

    // Create an edit link
    $link = l('Edit', "node/$nid/edit");

    // Add it to the element
    $form['field_lessons'][LANGUAGE_NONE][$key]['nid']['#suffix'] = $link;
  }
}
```

Comment: Soooooo close. This: $link = l('Edit', "node/$lesson[nid]/edit"); makes a link like this /node/Array/edit though. And unfortunately...the link breaks the drag & drop rearrange ability :s

Comment: Sorry about that I somehow forgot it was a form! I've updated the answer, it's tested so should work this time

Comment: Works, but I'm getting this error now on this line if (isset($lesson['nid']['#default_value']) && $lesson['nid']['#default_value'])...

Comment: What error are you getting?

Comment: Notice: Uninitialized string offset: 0

Comment: Hmm that's odd I don't get that error. Try changing the check to an `is_numeric` and moving it onto the next line and let me know if that helps

Comment: Problem remains...but its still on this line if (isset($lesson['nid']['#default_value']))

Comment: I'm taking a stab that the parser actually means the line before, and that the array hasn't been set up yet...I've updated the answer again

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/3621/discussion-between-somethingon-and-clive)